# Pysaprk: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

My PySpark code runs directly in hadoop cluster. But when i am opening this file it gives me this error :IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

```
with open("/tmp/CIP_UTILITIES/newjsonfile.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump("json_output", fp)
```

Comment: Don't you have to write the directory with `hdfs`?

Comment: I tried giving only the directory, still it fails

Comment: Did you try something like this: `"hdfs://localhost:port/tmp/CIP_UTILITIES/newjsonfile.json"` ?

Comment: Yeah, first i tried this. But it is not working

Answer (score -1):

for this cases when you are working with files it is better to use pathlib module.

Can you run Debug to see where this path is actually pointing?

greeting